# Qual a diferença do tipo de dados serial e integer no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou criando um banco de dados no PostgreSQL e bateu a dúvida como posso criar na tabela o campo ID com AUTO_INCREMENT, pesquisando na internet encontrei alguns exemplos com o campo ID com tipo de dados SERIAL e outros com tipo de dados INTEGER.

Qual a diferença entre esses 2 tipos de dados e qual podemos usar para ser o nosso ID com AUTO_INCREMENT no banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao definir um campo como `serial` o banco cria uma coluna do tipo `integer` ou `biginteger` com um `sequence` associada, ela é a responsável por incrementar o número. Se criar um campo apenas como `integer` fica a cargo do programador a lógica de como ele será incremento seja criar um `sequence` na mão, via aplicação etc.